# My kubernetes pods restarting randomly with sandbox changed event reason, causing downtime of my services

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, production-environment, kubernetes-ingress

We have setup Kubernetes on bare metal RHEL machine. Everything is working fine until we have noticed a random restart of all of the pods in the cluster.
As this is our production environment running in kubernetes cluster (kubectl git version 1.13.1), we cannot afford downtime of our services. But we are experiencing random restarts which causes few minutes of downtime of our services. Analyzing kubectl events, the reason it displays is **sandbox changed**. I manually logged in to all worker nodes and checked the docker containers. All containers on worker nodes restarted together. 
I am unable to come to any conclusion of this. This automatic restarts is happening on weekly basis. Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Following is the version:

```
Kubernetes v1.13.1
Docker 18.06.1-ce
```

Comment: Hi, is there any correlation within restart time? Most likely it is related to the network issue. What does `kubectl logs <pod-name>` say?

Comment: Yes, they seem to get restart on every Monday about 10:00 AM. I have googled the problem and professionals suggested to increase the resource limit of Flannel. I did that too, still all pods restarted today i.e. Monday 10 AM. I am unable to figure out the reason. :(

Comment: Can you try to pull logs of the pod prior restart `kubectl logs pod-name --previous`. If there's no sensetive data, pls put it here

Comment: Do your Pods have any resource limitations? It would help a lot if you share your deployment manifest

Comment: I pulled the logs using `--previous` directive but it doesnot have any info regarding restart. Only thing I found is in the output of `kubectl get events -n namespace` which showed the reason as SandBoxChanged.

Comment: @A_Suh Yes my pods have resource limitation. Only elasticsearch seems to reach the resource limit. But in that case only Elasticsearch pod should be rescheduled not the entire kubernetes pods.